# Should "Go to full Inbox" instead say "Go to all messages" or "Go to complete Inbox"?

Tags: support, bug, notifications, global-inbox

The link "Go to full Inbox" is unclear.

- Does it just mean go to your Inbox?
- Does it mean that your Inbox is in some way "full" (is there a limit?), and it's trying to tell you you need to go there and do something (e.g. delete some messages)?

Should it be changed to "Go to all messages" or maybe "Go to complete Inbox"?

Comment: I don't think I've never seen any software or site say "Go to full X" when the X is full to the top. It has always been "the complete X".